# How to validate complex list types in pydantic?

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

Why does pydantic not validate an argument that is the list of Foo objects but throws ValidationError when the argument is a list of primitive types?

Can I enforce the validation of complex types?

Validation doesn't work:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Foo(BaseModel):
    kind: str = "foo"

class Bar(BaseModel):
    kind: str = "bar"

class Spam(BaseModel):
    foos: List[Foo]

spam = Spam(foos=[Bar()])
print(spam.dict())

>>> {'foos': [{'kind': 'bar'}]}
```

Validation works:

```
class Spam(BaseModel):
    foos: List[int]


spam = Spam(foos=[Bar()])
print(spam.dict())

pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Spam
foos -> 0
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with `pydantic`, it should be remembered [that](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/):

> *pydantic* is primarily a parsing library, **not a validation library.** Validation is a means to an end: building a model which conforms to the types and constraints provided.
>
> In other words, **pydantic guarantees the types and constraints of the output model, not the input data**.

For additional validation of incoming data, a tool is provided - [validators](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/).
For example:

```
class Spam(BaseModel):
    foos: List[Foo]

    @validator('foos', pre=True, each_item=True)
    def check_squares(cls, v):
        assert isinstance(v, Foo), "Foo is only allowed"
        return v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't validate the value like `kind: str = "foo"`. You have to use [Field](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/) in order to validate values of a variable.

Try:

```
from typing import List

import pydantic
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Foo(BaseModel):
   kind: str = Field(const="foo", default="foo")

class Bar(BaseModel):
    kind: str = Field(const="bar", default="bar")

class Spam(BaseModel):
    foos: List[Foo]

try:
    Spam.parse_obj({'foos': [{'kind': 'bar'}]})
except pydantic.ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: That's good, but not exactly what I want. I want pydantic to raise ValidationError when foos argument is a list with items which types aren't Foo.

Comment: You can't differentiate between Foo and Bar since both contain the variable `kind`. You can change the kind to `foo` and `bar` and it'll throw validation error.