# Pydantic allows weird types on field with nested model

Tags: python, validation, fastapi, python-typing, pydantic

Currently i have this script:

```py
from typing import List
from uuid import uuid4, UUID

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Id(BaseModel):
    value:UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)

class User(BaseModel):
    id:Id = Field(default_factory=Id)
    roles:List[str] = ['student']

class Project(BaseModel):
    id:Id = Field(default_factory=Id)
    creator:User

id = Id()
print(id)

user = User()
print(user)

project = Project(creator={})
print(project)
```

The script should run as it is

When i instantiate a project, pydantic allows me to put non User objects, like dicts, strings, Id(objects of type Id) and some others, but i feel this is not expected. The weirdest thing is the fields are auto filled with an object of the correct type when a bad value is passed

what is happening here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700810/how-to-validate-complex-list-types-in-pydantic

Comment: But why is pydantic autofilling the field with a default object of Type User?